# How to use variable in Command prompt used by Java Program?

Tags: java, pdf, command-line

I have this program.

```
try {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            //Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c dir");
            Process pr = rt.exec("java -jar C:/sample/sample.jar D:/pdftest.pdf");
            BufferedReader input1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

            String line=null;

            while((line=input1.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }               

            int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal);

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Here , process pr defines a command. Now my question, I want to replace the part "D:/pdftest.pdf" to a variable like

```
String pdfvariable="D:/pdftest.pdf";
```

So I should be able to replace hard coded value of "D:/pdftest.pdf" to pdfvariable. 
Is it possible? Can anyone please explain it to me?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String pdfvariable = "D:/pdftest.pdf";
Process pr = rt.exec("java -jar C:/sample/sample.jar " + pdfVariable);
```

Comment: I tried but doesnt seem to work..Did you try this in your system?

Comment: It's just a string concatenation. It's basic Java.  Did you copy it *exactly*? Or have you changed the filename (e.g. introduced a filename with a space in it)? Are you getting an error message? Are you sure it works correctly when you don't use the pdfVariable?

Comment: Did you forget to insert the space at the end immediately before the quote?

Comment: Yeah I had tried this before and when you suggested, I tried again..I didnt copy exactly but changed some file names...but does that matter?The thing is the application which i use doesnt recognize the variable...

Comment: Also, I wanted to ask that since this is a command line, how ll exec convert variable?

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I tried...the mistake what i was doin was that i didnt give space after "jar"...thanks a lot..